# Why typescript not report error when give a different type of data to component's attribute in Angular2

Tags: angular

All:

I am pretty new to Angular2, say I define a App component and a SubCom component:

**subcom.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sub-com',
  template: `
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#t of target">{{t}}</li>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class SubCom {
    @Input() target: number;
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {SubCom} from "./subcom.component";

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <sub-com [target]="hello"></sub-com>
  `,
  directives: [SubCom]
})
export class AppComponent {
  hello: string[] = ["Alice", "Bob"];
}
```

When I run this, the SubCom can tell target is array and build that ngFor list. But I defined target as number in SubCom, **why no error related reported when TypeScript gets transpiled**?

Thanks

Comment: Check this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6919)

Comment: @EricMartinez So, does this mean my question still not resolved on Angular side?

Comment: no, it hasn't been resolved, and I don't think this is an issue but that's completely a personal opinion. If you have a use case for this you can add your thoughts in that issue. And you could follow @robwormald' suggestion `This could probably done with a wrapper around the @Input, or with a setter for most cases....`